# cover div or image with transparent color

Tags: css

I have a div, and an image inside it. on the image I have the DB results, designed and placed with relative location on each div.
I want to cover some of the results (the most interesting one with color overlay), see image bellow:
[image]

How should I do it without adding another div on top of it?
backgroup will not help here, because the image is higher z index than the div..

I want to be able to do it as easiest as I can with CSS, because I will get the property from the DB query , and set the class for the relevant result rows..

Does someone has creative idea please? :)

Thanks.

Comment: css: `filter: hue-rotate(90deg);`

Comment: Use an absolutely placed pseudo-element as an overlay.

Comment: do you mean   -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);   
it will not help, because I need to paint the white as well.. hue will not change white..

Comment: add invert(100%) to turn white to black and color that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all,
So I am checking on the DB for the property, if exist I am appending new div as child for the result Div and this is the CSS:

```
div.cheapest {
 background: red;
 z-index:85;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 opacity:.3;
}
```

Comment: I guess discarding all the other answers to put and choose your own is one way to earn reputation...

Comment: No, it is not fair what you are doing, I took the comment of @Pauli_d (gave him reputation of course) and used it, and this is what fits me the most and this is the reason I put it as answer, so people will see it if needed.. It is different Technic than yours, I am not using the :before and relative position..

Comment: It is the same thing, except where I'm using pseudo-elements, you're adding DOM, and you're modifying the whole block opacity where i'm only I'm only modifying the background's so if you ever wanted to put text in this overlay then it would appear normally. Also, Paulie_D suggested what I did in my answer. PS: I don't really care about reputation, but adding your own answer to basically do what someone did in another answer doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: Ok, did not understood it as you describe now. will give you the answer , sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded douchey, that was definitely not the intent. Let me make my last comment clearer. You were using the `opacity` property to modify the transparency of your overlay. This implies that if you overlay itself contains some sub-elements, they will themselves be also transparent. Using an `rgba` background prevents this, because only the background of your overlay will be transparent. As for the pseudo-element part, your overlay doesn't seem to be a content, so as such, it shouldn't be in your DOM, this is what the pseudo-elements `before` and `after` are for.

Answer (score 8):

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
div:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

You can also change the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` values to offset the overlay from the image borders.

Comment: The `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` values change the overlay offset from the screen. Any thoughts on how to use it from the div it's on top of?

Answer (score 4):

well, with all the restrictions you have, the only thing I can think is this:

```
div{background:#f00}
img{opacity:.5}
```

not very elegant, but will work

Comment: ohh it is nice idea.. I am checking the "another div" solution now.. but your idea very good solution..

Comment: Arrr.. not good for me.. I have elements in top of the background image with white background.. I thing I need to check the solution of having div on top of the populated div..

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I was thinking to overlay the image with an alpha image until hovered, but [this](https://jsfiddle.net/oaao4uy7/1/) accomplishes the same visual. I change the opacity to .9 in my case though.